# Как в джанго устроена навигация по вкладкам?

Tags: html, django, url

Я знаю что каждую отдельную страницу в django можно создать в файле views.py
но что если при переходе мне нужно изменить только небольшую часть шаблона
И достаточно только одной переменной с условием if в html шаблоне.

Я знаю несколько вариантов но все они мне не подходят

Хранить весь динамический html в БД а после выводить его с помощью

```
path('page/<int:page_id>/', views.page, name = 'page')
```

не подходит потому что засоряет бд ненужным мусором и при развертывании на другом сервере придется писать все заново.

Использовать метод `POST` сохраняя все в переменной `where` а после возвращать ее и проверять в `html` шаблоне с помощью

```
{% if where == 1 %}
```

не подходит потому что при обновлении или отправки нового запроса все сбрасывается.

использовать `CSS` в связке с `Radio` тоже не подходит так как каждый раз приходится загружать весь код сначала и опять же при обновлении страницы он сбрасывается

Можно ли использовать что-то наподобие \page?tab=1 с

```
 {% if tab== 1 %}
```

для быстрого и легкого перехода межу вкладками одной страницы

или как в django это устроено может кто нибудь мне рассказать?

Comment: Есть `request.GET` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict https://metanit.com/python/django/3.4.php

Comment: @mrEvgenX Спасибо большое. А вы не знаете ка более правильно сделать переключение? единственный вариант который я знаю это  `{% url   'current_saite'  %} "?tab=1"`